# Autorization token from React doesn't pass Java Spring Boot filter

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, authorization, token, client-server

I'm building an app that has a backend in Java Spring boot, and a frontend in React. To pass a token from client to server I'm using a filter class that looks like this:

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class ApplicationFilter implements Filter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetails userDetails;
    
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        
        String token = httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization").substring(7);
        
        Jws<Claims> jwsParsed = null;
        try {
             jwsParsed = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                    .setSigningKey("Yn2kjibddFAWtnPJ2AFlL8WXmohJMCvigQggaEypa5E=".getBytes())
                    .build()
                    .parseClaimsJws(token);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("The token is not correct.");
        }

        Long id = jwsParsed.getBody().get("id", Long.class);
        String name = jwsParsed.getBody().get("name", String.class);
        
        userDetails.setUserId(id);
        userDetails.setUserName(name);
        
        chain.doFilter(httpRequest, response);
    }
```

In addition to this I'm configuring web config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE","POST","GET")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .exposedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

to let the requests pass the CORS policy. And also I've configured the context listener to use request context in the app:

```
@Configuration
public class RequestContextListenerConfig {
    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }
}
```

> Blockquote

On the client-side I'm defining an authentication service:

```
class AuthApiService {
    api = null;

    constructor() {
        this.api = axios.create();

        this.api
            .interceptors
            .request
            .use(config => {
                config.baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/";
                config.headers = {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${loginService.getUserToken()}`
                };
                return config;
            });
    }

    getApi = () => this.api;
}

const authApiService = new AuthApiService();
export const authApi = authApiService.getApi();
export default authApiService;
```

and use it in my requests like this:

```
addItem(item) {
authApi.post("image", item)
    .then((response) => {
        item.id = response.data.id;
        this.galleryItems.push(item);
        this.dataWasChanged.next("ADD");
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err.response);
    });
}
```

The problem is when I'm running this add function it gives me an error in the console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

and also in java:

```
ERROR 46280 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
Cannot invoke "String.substring(int)" because the return value of "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHeader(String)" is null
```

Never the less I'm sure that the token was sent because before an error I see it printed in the console. Besides, when I'm getting to the app through Postman, everything works with the token.

I printed header from Postman, and they are:

```
Header 'authorization' = Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJPbGdhIiwic3ViIjoiZ2FsbGVyeUFwcCIsImlkIjoyLCJuYW1lIjoiTWF4IiwiaWF0IjoxNjM1MTkwMDA5LCJleHAiOjE2Mzc4NzIwMDl9.KV7PNXDIITMQcmzsLOF0WMF34-t4PP47URMoiGJYvvs
Header 'content-type' = application/json
Header 'user-agent' = PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
Header 'accept' = */*
Header 'postman-token' = 21eee286-c554-442f-a169-ab82926165f7
Header 'host' = localhost:8080
Header 'accept-encoding' = gzip, deflate, br
Header 'connection' = keep-alive
Header 'content-length' = 85
```

but from the browser request I see these headers:

```
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
accept: */*
access-control-request-method: POST
access-control-request-headers: authorization,content-type
origin: http://localhost:3000
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
sec-fetch-dest: empty
referer: http://localhost:3000/
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.7
```

No authorization header at all.

So the question is why the authorization token doesn't come to the java code from the react client? What am I doing wrong, where can be a bug? Or is there any other way to receive the token from the headers that I'm sending to the server?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) is blocked by Spring Security filter.
You will need additional [CORS configuration for Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.3/reference/html5/#cors).

```java
@Configuration
// unnecessary in most cases
// https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-web-applications.spring-mvc.auto-configuration
// @EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE","POST","GET")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .exposedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
 protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     // if disabling CSRF protection
     // https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.3/reference/html5/#csrf-when
     http.csrf().disable();

     // if Spring MVC is on classpath and no CorsConfigurationSource is provided,
     // Spring Security will use CORS configuration provided to Spring MVC
     http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
 }
}
```